# Sequelize: Querying if ARRAY contains a value

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Suppose I have a PG ARRAY field:

```
id |    array    |
===|=============|
  1|{"1","2","3"}|
```

How do I use sequelize to query to see if the array field as the value `1`.

I tried:

```
array: { $contains: "1" }
```

which gives me:

```
array @> "1"
```

with error:

```
Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

#### UPDATE

I was able to do it by:
    array: { $contains: '{' + value + '}' }

Is there a more correct way?

Comment: Are you storing serialized data in your database, or is that just a visualization?

Comment: no it is not serialized. it is a PG ARRAY datatype.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I realised that sequelize is expecting the condition to be an array:

```
array: { [Op.contains]: ["1"] }
```

That will work. Cheers!!

Bear in mind that `Op` is exported from `sequelize`

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
```

or

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
```

See official docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

Comment: Update: new syntax is `array: { [Op.contains] : ["1"] }`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe so.

```
`{ genres: { $contains: [genreType] } }`
```

`genres` is an array. `genreType` can also be an array.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */,
  operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op.Aliases,
});
```