# Sequelize Custom Field seperated from tables

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am trying to make an IN query but the field that I am querying is not an element of the table. It is hardcoded.

```
await models.users.findOne({
  where: {
    id: 12,
    2: {$in: [1, 2, 3]}
  }
});
```

The problem is, sequelize puts the table name to begin of my field.

```
WHERE `users`.`2` IN (1, 2, 3)
```

As there is no field **2** in my table it throws "Unknown column 'users.2' in where clause"

Actually, this is what I need and works in native sql:

```
WHERE 2 IN (1, 2, 3)
```

**UPDATE**

To explain it better I am writing the whole SQL:

```
    SELECT count(`users`.`id`) AS `count`
    FROM `users` AS `users`
      INNER JOIN `payment_log` AS `succeed_payment`
        ON `users`.`id` = `succeed_payment`.`user_id` AND `succeed_payment`.`state` = 'success'
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_profile` AS `profile` ON `users`.`id` = `profile`.`user_id` AND `profile`.`state` = 'submitted'
    WHERE
      `users`.`country` = 'BLR'
      AND (`users`.`kyc_state` IN ('prepared', 'applicant_created', 'consider') OR `users`.`kyc_state` IS NULL)
    GROUP BY `users`.`id`
    HAVING
      1 IN ((SELECT tag_id
             FROM user_tags UT
             WHERE users.id = UT.user_id)) AND
      2 IN ((SELECT tag_id
             FROM user_tags UT
             WHERE users.id = UT.user_id));
```

1 and 2 come from the URL query. I am checking if the customer has those tags.

Unfortunately, sequelize adds backticks to my query and returns it to this:

```
  HAVING
    `1` IN ((SELECT tag_id
             FROM user_tags UT
             WHERE users.id = UT.user_id)) AND
    `2` IN ((SELECT tag_id
             FROM user_tags UT
             WHERE users.id = UT.user_id));
```

in that case I receive "unkown column 1" error

Comment: Good question, I don't know if there's a builtin support for this, however, you can always use [raw-queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use raw-query, this is just a basic example of the query. It is too big to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize: Querying if ARRAY contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036363/sequelize-querying-if-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: No, it is a very different case.

Comment: Doesn't matter what I put there it adds "users." prefix. My problem is completely different than that one. The result of that try is here:

WHERE `users`.`1,2,3` @> 2

Comment: is `[1, 2, 3]` an attribute of `users` ?

Comment: No, they are not. Actually, I realised now if I use HAVING it doesn't add "users." But it adds backticks and it still says "Unknown column `1`"

Comment: if neither the `2` nor `[1,2,3]` are coming from the table - why is it in the query to begin with? there `where` clause is meaningless...

Comment: thank you very much alfasin, you effort a lot to solve the issue. I am very thankful. I updated the question.

Comment: You can try doing instead: `(SELECT count(tag_id) FROM user_tags UT WHERE users.id = UT.user_id) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can achievie that by :

```
where : {
    '$2$' : {$in: [1, 2, 3]}
}
```

Comment: This removed the table name from query (*users.*) but sequelize still puts the backticks and therefore MySQL says *unknown column 1*